# How to Assign a class to a custom UIView in Swift?

Tags: storyboard, swift, interface-builder

I'm trying to create a custom framework so that I can use @IBDesignable to render my view in the storyboard. Normally you can click on the view in the storyboard and select a class from the drop-down in inspector. Since I must assign my custom framework from the dropdown, I now have to create a custom subview within my framework and assign my class too that ((which is a class from graphical circle counter I downloaded from cocoapods `JWGCircleCounter`). I'm not sure how to do this in S in XCode 6 in Swift. Here is the code for my custom framework so far:

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable
class CircleTimer: UIView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        var outerCircle = UIView.class(JWGCircleCounter)(frame CGRectmake: 22, 137, 125, 125)        //This is my guess at how to assign the class, thought of course it doesn't work. I'm also not sure where to delcare the frame after assigning the class
    self.addSubview(outerCircle)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should Make the instance of `JWGCircleCounter` as `JWGCircleCounter`  is subclass of `UIView`.
As `JWGCircleCounter` has intializer `init(frame:CGRect)` you can call this to make instance.

Also in `swift`

```
class CircleTimer: UIView {
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    var outerCircle:JWGCircleCounter = JWGCircleCounter(frame: CGRectMake(22, 137, 125, 125))       //This is my guess at how to assign the class, thought of course it doesn't work. I'm also not sure where to delcare the frame after assigning the class
    self.addSubview(outerCircle)
}
```

`JWGCircleCounter` is subclass of `UIView` and it already override `init(frame:)` so you can call this to make an instance.

And note you should always pass instance of sub class(`JWGCircleCounter`) to super class( `UIView`) not vice versa.Refer [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)

**EDIT** : For cocoa pods you can try

Select your Project file (Blue on the top right) and go into `Build Settings`. Then, find `'Allow non-modular includes in Framework Modules'` and set it to **YES**, for both the Project file (blue) and the Custom Framework target

Comment: Now getting an error "Use of undeclared type 'JWGCircleCounter', however I have properly  imported the cocoapod header into my swift bridging header for the project. Also in the header file that was generated when the framework was created I also tried importing the same 'JWCCircleCounter' header file and got the same error. So I think the trouble I am having now is getting the Framework to see the JWCCircleCounter cocoapod. My app sees it at the project level, but not at the "framework level"

Comment: Do not use `cocoapod` with swift currently there are problems with `cocoapod` and swift interoperatability

Comment: My app is in Swift and most of it is developed using 5 different cocoapods. Is there an way to make the framework "see" my project's cocoapod libraries?